# Android PHP Query returns user exists despite not being true

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Can someone help me check why my query keeps returning the user exists despite me entering a whole set of new data? The code should be correct? I have been testing this code for awhile and I can't see where its gone wrong.

The request is sent from the app and then it takes the data via post. However something is preventing me from inserting a new row.

```
$checkuserexistsquery = "SELECT email, phone FROM users WHERE email='$email' OR phone='$phone'";
$insertuserquery = "INSERT INTO users (firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,phone,email,password) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$dateofbirth','$phone','$email','$password')";
$checkuserexistsresults = mysqli_query($conn,$checkuserexistsquery);
if($checkuserexistsresults===FALSE){
    echo "Check user query failed";
}else{
    $countcheckuserexistsresults = mysqli_num_rows($checkuserexistsresults);
    if($countcheckuserexistsresults>0){
        //user already exists
        echo "User already exists";
    }else{
        //user doesn't exist
        $insertuserresults = mysqli_query($conn,$insertuserquery);
        if($insertuserresults===FALSE){
            echo "Insert user query failed";
        }else{
            echo "Insert successful";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Does it say that `user already exists` or does it only not insert the data?

Comment: why don't you just `echo $checkuserexistsresults;` and see the result?

Comment: It says user already exists only. Good idea. Ill echo and see

Comment: maybe you need `echo mysqli_fetch_array($checkuserexistsresults);` instead

Comment: I had to put a while loop to echo it. However it returned a row from the database that has nothing to do with what I entered.

Comment: what is the email and phone you sent? and what is the email and phone from db?

Comment: sent : t@t.com and 4444 db: test@test.com and 12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, i think you should confirm if `$email` and `$phone` should be the correct one that you want. You can `echo` or `var_dump` them before concat it to `$checkuserexistsquery`. I presume that maybe you assign the values, `email: test@test.com` or `phone: 12345` somewhere else in your code, because i don't see any logical error from your code.

Comment: Thank you! I found the root of the issue. Its good to know that my sql is not the one giving me the problem haha.